Repeating headings only when needed
I am editing an existing HTML report template with headings on the left (example below).
This works when only one or two items are listed as they default to the right but when additional items are loaded, I need these to repeat on a new line.
Can I make it so an additional line comes up with these on the left ONLY when the extra line is needed?
<section class="keep-together">
  <h5 class="uptick-title no-page-break-after">Results</h5>
  <p>The system results as follows.</p>
  {% if all_servicetasks %}
    <div class="clearfix">
      <dl < class="float-left">
        <dt>Asset</dt>
        <dt>These results indicate:</dt>
        <dt>Location:</dt>
        <dt>Fitting:</dt>
      </dl>

I have tried some googled answers such as  and altering some of the existing code with no luck

Welcome to [so] - please take the [tour] and read our [ask] for tips on how to improve this question. As it stands, it's hard to understand what you are having issues with.  Also, for faster troubleshooting, please consider including a [mre] that shows the issue you are having

{% if all_servicetasks %} or <dl < class="float-left"> are invalids in HTML

So, I am considering your HTML is correct, you have made a mistake here pasting/writing <dl < class="float-left"> and {% if all_servicetasks %} is a comment,
Then your solution is in two steps:

give some width to parent div (with class clearfix) and accordingly give width to <dd> which means description not more than 100%;
and once <dd> has width applied, use css property word-wrap: break-word; on <dd>

Example:
HTML:
<div class="clearfix">
  <dl class="float-left">
    <dt>Asset</dt>
    <dd>large content</dd>
  </dl>
</div>

CSS:
dd {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 95vw; //(I gave for testing, update acc. to need)
  border: 1px solid red;
}

Hope this helps.
Reference: w3schools css3_pr_word-wrap
